# Matplotlib v 3 Length mismatch ValueError: Expected axis has x elements, new values have x+1 elements

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using Matplotlib version 3.2.1 with Python 3.7 and pandas 1.0.3.

I'm using the following code which results in a length mismatch error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mpl_dates
df_train = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv', date_parser=True)
df_train.columns = ['date', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']
df_train['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_train['date'])
df_train.set_index(['date'])

x_value = df_train['date']
y_value = df_train['col4']
plt.plot_date(x_value, y_value, 'g')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

which results in the following error:

```
     File "C:\Users\brohj\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 178, in set_axis
    f"Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old_len} elements, new "
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 6 elements, new values have 7 elements
```

(Note: There is no typo in the error message.  Copied directly as is.)

What gives?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is these two lines:

```
df_train = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv', date_parser=True)
df_train.columns = ['date', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']
```

which I believe your data in `csv` does not have a name for index. You can do:

```
# read and parse index as date
df_train = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=[0])

# rename column
df_train.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']

# rename index
df_train.index.name = 'date'

df_train.plot(y='col4', c='g')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Quang, but your code results in a correctly rendered green line chart with row numbers on the x-axis.

Comment: At second though, you might need to review your `csv` file if it contains `date` at all.

Comment: It does.  This question stems from an answer received from my previous question. As you can see in the graphs, it will display the dates, but when it's displaying dates, the graph is rendered incorrectly (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62129895/issue-with-matplotlib-rendering-dates-image

Comment: You data has only 6 columns, including `date` :-). Let my update my answer.